# Outlook Addin development - Sideloading rejected by exchange

Tags: outlook-web-addins, sideloading

We are trying to develop outlook Addin . Here is official [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/quickstarts/outlook-quickstart?tabs=yeomangenerator).
Development is straightforward. Installation also can be done in Exchange by the exchange administrator.

The problem is testing during the development. When using the this [guide](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=atCCIXRAtf0) uploaded the manifest in outlook, I got error - `Sideloading rejected by exchange`.

My exchange administrator does not have any clue, how to get rid of this and developers are asking how to test the developed code?  Can someone tell how to do the development of addin and test, without repeatedly sharing manifest with exchange administrator? As, in an enterprise, uploading manifest in exchange is a 2-3 weeks process following change request process.

- Is there any other way than Sideloading to test the add in ?
- Is there any configuration available for exchange administrator, to allow sideloading for a specific group of developers?

Answer (score 0):

I also got this issue trying to side-load using the manifest.xml created by the generator. I think there is an issue with the template. It works for me when I use a sample from the [Office-Add-in-samples](https://github.com/OfficeDev/Office-Add-in-samples) repo. The one I tried specifically was the [outlook-set-signature](https://github.com/OfficeDev/Office-Add-in-samples/tree/main/Samples/outlook-set-signature) sample.